# Sending an array of objects to GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to feed an array of objects from a React app to GraphQL. But I'm getting this error:

```
   Error: The type of Mutation.reorderFields(fieldsOrder:) must be Input Type but got: [orderField].
```

This is my schema:

```
  reorderFields(
    fieldsOrder:[orderField]
  ):Boolean!
```

Mutation:

```
  type orderField{
    order: Int,
    myform: String,
    id: String,
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: But doesn't that mean that the type of the orderField should be boolean, or do I read it absolutely wrong?

Comment: @JaakkoKarhu the :Boolean is the return type of the reaorderFields() not the input type.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem might be on GraphQL server.
Because your *orderField* is defined as object type and it probably should be defined as a input type.

In GraphQL mutation the data payload needs to be defined as input type.

Check [Mutations and Input Types](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/) for a better description on how to make mutations.